# How to open dialog from a function in react?

Tags: reactjs, dialog, material-ui, scheduler, react-props

I am currently using this [code](https://github.com/StephenChou1017/react-big-scheduler/blob/master/example/ResourceClickable.js) to create my scheduler application.

This is my code now - Scheduler.js

```
class CalendarScheduler extends Component {
state = {
    viewModel: schedulerData,
    showBookingDialog: true,
}

handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState( (prevState) => {
        return {showBookingDialog : !prevState.showBookingDialog};
    } )
};

handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ showBookingDialog: false });
};

render() {
    const { viewModel } = this.state;

    let schedulerData = this.state.viewModel;
    schedulerData.setResources(this.props.rooms);

    return (
        <div>
            <Scheduler schedulerData={viewModel}
                prevClick={this.prevClick}
                nextClick={this.nextClick}
                onSelectDate={this.onSelectDate}
                newEvent={this.newEvent}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

In Scheduler.js, I have a function for newEvent:

```
newEvent = (schedulerData, slotId, slotName, start, end, type, item) => {
    return(
        <BookingDialog 
            open={this.state.showBookingDialog}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            />
    );
}
```

**My question is why when I click on the scheduler to create a new event, it doesnt open up my BookingDialog?**

The previous newEvent function uses window.confirm, which can be found [here](https://github.com/StephenChou1017/react-big-scheduler/blob/master/example/ResourceClickable.js) in line 93.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a state variable in your Scheduler component to show BookingDialog, And in newEvent function make that state variable as 'true'.And in scheduler component, view the BookingDialog based on this state variable.

```
newEvent = (schedulerData, slotId, slotName, start, end, type, item) => {
this.setState({showBookingDialog:true})
}
```

and in Scheduler component

```
{this.state.showBookingDialog && <BookingDialog 
        open={this.state.showBookingDialog}
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        />}
```

Comment: Hello, i did the above changes but still facing a problem. 

when i click on my scheduler, i am expected the dialog to open. But i am facing this error message: Unable to find node on an unmounted component.

This error is pointed to the "this.setState" in side newEvent. 

Please help as i have been facing this problem for days. Thank you!!

Comment: could you please post your code in codesandbox/stackblitz , so that it will be clear